Matlab webread returning empty char, what am I missing?
I'm trying to query spacetrack.org from Matlab and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm only getting an empty char from the output of webread. I have a Python function working that accomplishes this.
Python Function:
import requests
import urllib.parse

def query_space_track(username, password, norad_id):
    try:
        # Perform login to get session cookie
        login_url = 'https://www.space-track.org/ajaxauth/login'
        login_data = {'identity': username, 'password': password}
        with requests.Session() as session:
            login_response = session.post(login_url, data=login_data)
            print(login_data)

            cookie = login_response.cookies.get_dict()
            # Construct URL for TLE query
            query_url = 'https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/NORAD_CAT_ID/{norad_id}/orderby/EPOCH desc/limit/1/format/tle'

            # Perform TLE query
            tle_response = requests.get(query_url, cookies=cookie)
            
            if tle_response.status_code == 200:
                return tle_response.text
            else:
                print(f"Error: {tle_response.status_code} - {tle_response.reason}")
                return ''
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return ''

What I'm trying in Matlab:
spacetrack_base = 'https://www.space-track.org';
auth_endpoint = '/ajaxauth/login';

login_data = struct('identity', username, 'password', password);

login_options = weboptions('MediaType', 'application/json', ...
                               'RequestMethod', 'POST', ...
                               'HeaderFields', {'Content-Type', 'application/json'});        
login_response = webwrite([spacetrack_base auth_endpoint], login_data, login_options);

Is this the correct way to login to the auth endpoint and collect the cookie from the session?
